# Tensorflow: UnavailableError: OS Error when increase the worker (distributed GPU mode)

Tags: tensorflow

I'm running tensorflowOnSpark with 1 namenode and 4 datanodes
each datanode has 4  Titan xp (so 16 GPUS all together)

the 'Hello Tensorflow' runs like below for every datanode

```
Python 3.5.2 (default, Feb  7 2018, 11:42:44) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow as tf
hello = tf.constant('Hello, TensorFlow!')
sess = tf.Session()
print(sess.run(hello))
>>> hello = tf.constant('Hello, TensorFlow!')
>>> sess = tf.Session()
2018-02-07 20:54:37.894085: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1206] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: TITAN Xp major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.582
pciBusID: 0000:03:00.0
totalMemory: 11.91GiB freeMemory: 11.71GiB
2018-02-07 20:54:38.239744: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1206] Found device 1 with properties: 
name: TITAN Xp major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.582
pciBusID: 0000:04:00.0
totalMemory: 11.91GiB freeMemory: 11.74GiB
2018-02-07 20:54:38.587283: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1206] Found device 2 with properties: 
name: TITAN Xp major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.582
pciBusID: 0000:83:00.0
totalMemory: 11.91GiB freeMemory: 11.74GiB
2018-02-07 20:54:38.922914: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1206] Found device 3 with properties: 
name: TITAN Xp major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.582
pciBusID: 0000:84:00.0
totalMemory: 11.91GiB freeMemory: 11.74GiB
2018-02-07 20:54:38.927574: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1221] Device peer to peer matrix
2018-02-07 20:54:38.927719: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1227] DMA: 0 1 2 3 
2018-02-07 20:54:38.927739: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1237] 0:   Y Y N N 
2018-02-07 20:54:38.927750: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1237] 1:   Y Y N N 
2018-02-07 20:54:38.927760: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1237] 2:   N N Y Y 
2018-02-07 20:54:38.927774: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1237] 3:   N N Y Y 
2018-02-07 20:54:38.927791: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1300] Adding visible gpu device 0
2018-02-07 20:54:38.927804: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1300] Adding visible gpu device 1
2018-02-07 20:54:38.927816: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1300] Adding visible gpu device 2
2018-02-07 20:54:38.927827: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1300] Adding visible gpu device 3
2018-02-07 20:54:40.194789: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:987] Creating TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 11341 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: TITAN Xp, pci bus id: 0000:03:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)
2018-02-07 20:54:40.376314: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:987] Creating TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:1 with 11374 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 1, name: TITAN Xp, pci bus id: 0000:04:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)
2018-02-07 20:54:40.556361: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:987] Creating TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:2 with 11374 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 2, name: TITAN Xp, pci bus id: 0000:83:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)
2018-02-07 20:54:40.740179: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:987] Creating TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:3 with 11374 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 3, name: TITAN Xp, pci bus id: 0000:84:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)
>>> print(sess.run(hello))
b'Hello, TensorFlow!'
```

for this hardware setting, mnist example with 8 executors (resulting that each data node is landed by two executor) can run, some of the worker may meet the error "OS Error" below but after its auto-retry it will get into training normally, and finally output the model as expected.

```
18/02/07 21:05:36 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 13.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 13)
org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/python3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1350, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "/usr/local/python3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1320, in _run_fn
    self._extend_graph()
  File "/usr/local/python3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1381, in _extend_graph
    self._session, graph_def.SerializeToString(), status)
  File "/usr/local/python3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py", line 473, in __exit__
    c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.UnavailableError: OS Error

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/disk0/yarn/usercache/zhanbohan/appcache/application_1518005864023_0002/container_1518005864023_0002_01_000016/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 177, in main
    process()
  File "/home/disk0/yarn/usercache/zhanbohan/appcache/application_1518005864023_0002/container_1518005864023_0002_01_000016/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 172, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
  File "/home/disk0/yarn/usercache/zhanbohan/appcache/application_1518005864023_0002/container_1518005864023_0002_01_000001/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2423, in pipeline_func
  File "/home/disk0/yarn/usercache/zhanbohan/appcache/application_1518005864023_0002/container_1518005864023_0002_01_000001/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2423, in pipeline_func
  File "/home/disk0/yarn/usercache/zhanbohan/appcache/application_1518005864023_0002/container_1518005864023_0002_01_000001/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2423, in pipeline_func
  File "/home/disk0/yarn/usercache/zhanbohan/appcache/application_1518005864023_0002/container_1518005864023_0002_01_000001/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2423, in pipeline_func
  File "/home/disk0/yarn/usercache/zhanbohan/appcache/application_1518005864023_0002/container_1518005864023_0002_01_000001/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 346, in func
  File "/home/disk0/yarn/usercache/zhanbohan/appcache/application_1518005864023_0002/container_1518005864023_0002_01_000001/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 794, in func
```

However, when tune the executor number to 16, the error above appear more frequently and no worker can get into training, finally the job failed and quit. The cluster should expected to be shift each executor on one GPU as we have 16 GPUs. And for the single node tensorflow test, all the GPU is accessible. (In the PCI board it may only be accessible within pairs 0-1 and 2-3, but it should not influence the executor communication in my opinion)

Another trial is that after I start a job with 8 executor running and every GPU begins to train, I start another job with 8 executor, the second job still failed with the same situation as 16 executors.

The log for 16 executor run is in the attach, together with the run script. Plz check and help me find out what's the case. Thanks.

[log.16.txt](https://github.com/yahoo/TensorFlowOnSpark/files/1703283/log.16.txt)
[run_mnist.sh.txt](https://github.com/yahoo/TensorFlowOnSpark/files/1703284/run_mnist.sh.txt)